# StandardXAConnectionHandle:prepareStatement should not be used outside an EJBServer

Tags: java, database, tomcat, jdbc, transactions

I have a web application deployed in a Tomcat 5.5 container. I use a `SessionEventListener` bean that logs some activities in the database. Sometimes I get this error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: StandardXAConnectionHandle:prepareStatement should not be used outside an EJBServer
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXAConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(StandardXAConnectionHandle.java:310)
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXAConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(StandardXAConnectionHandle.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:233)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:532)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:739)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:762)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:213)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:217)
    at hu.rate.session.RateDBSessionRegistry$4.doInTransactionWithoutResult(RateDBSessionRegistry.java:124)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:33)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:127)
    at hu.rate.session.RateDBSessionRegistry.refreshLastRequest(RateDBSessionRegistry.java:120)
```

The code that fails is the following:

```
txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(
                    TransactionStatus paramTransactionStatus) {
                if(template.update(us, paramMap) == 0) {
                    logger.warn("No session in registry to be refreshed, sessionId = " + sessionId);
                }
            }
        });

public void setTxManager(PlatformTransactionManager txManager) {
         txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
    }
```

My Spring bean config looks like this:

```
<bean id="jotm" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JotmFactoryBean" />
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="userTransaction">
            <ref local="jotm" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I do not really understand this issue, can you explain me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: today the same problem came again. starting a bounty now to see if someone could help me.

Comment: Could you enable debug log level and see how far it goes in StandardXAConnectionHandle? When you use JDBC are you demaracting transactions yourself or dealing with connection somewhere? This could interfere with how transaction and connection are managed with JTA--essentially, with JTA you should not deal with that at all. Maybe the connection has been closed, the tx committed, or I don't know what, which can create time-dependent bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Database-JDBC-Connection-Pool/xapool/org/enhydra/jdbc/standard/StandardXAConnectionHandle.java.htm) I found it looks like it is caused by an underlying NullPointerException.  Also interestingly enough, there is a comment in that code right below it on if you want to use PreparedStatements you need to comment out two lines and uncomment two other lines. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: thank you, I also saw this comment, but changing the source and recompiling XAPool is not an option for me. I solved the problem by reverting to plain-old JDBC code, but the bounty is still there because I'd like to get a nice explanation what did I wrong.

Comment: ahh, you should post your answer either way, so others know how to solve. Maybe do it after the bounty expires or is awarded?

Comment: You're right, however what I did (switching back to JDBC) is not a solution nor an answer to my question.